# Comparing files using timestamp in Python

Tags: python, timestamp, file-comparison

I'm trying to compare my files with the timestamp.
 For example, there is a directory with files, like
a.xls, a.log, a.txt
b.xls, b.log, b.txt
c.xls, c.log, c.txt
here i have to find whether the timestamp(datetime) of a.log and a.txt is greater than timestamp of a.xls
I did research about how to get a timestamp of a file, comparing timestamp of two files.
I don't know whether I'm going in a correct direction.
Please direct me how to look into this problem and give some logical guidance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask This question should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python

Comment: @L.Clarkson thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to write a code for the above question.

```py
import os
path = 'D:/Newfolder/A'
xls_file = []
for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith('xls'):   
        file_name = (i.split('.')[0])  
        ext_name = (i.split('.')[1])   
        xls_file.append(file_name)   
for fname in os.listdir(path):  
    for i in xls_file: 
        if fname.__contains__(i) and not fname.endswith('xls'):
            log_txt = os.path.getmtime(path+'/'+fname)   
            xls_tym = os.path.getmtime(path+'/'+i+'.xls')  
            if xls_tym < log_txt:
                pass
            else:
                print(i+'.xls')
```

It may not be the clean code,but i think the code works fine
Please suggest if any changes had to be made

Comment: A suggestion, have a look at [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) and [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for the handling of paths and filenames. Also, avoid the direct usage of dunderscore methods like `fname.__contains__(i)` - there're more readable alternatives like e.g. `i in fname`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python if you are able to create a datetime object then you can compare them using comparison operators.

So to get a datetime object of your file you can do this:

```
modTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getmtime(filePath)
 # Convert seconds since epoch to readable timestamp
modificationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(modTimesinceEpoc))
```

Then you can directly use the timestamp and compare them and get your desired output.

Hope this helps.